# how to focus pop up window?

Tags: javascript, popup, popupwindow

The given below code for open popup window it will open but i want to focus on popup window. And i'm trying scriptTag.focus();, but it will not worked anyone give suggestion to clear that issue.

```
var scriptTag = "window.open('"+serverURL+"','popUpWindow','height=500,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes')";
scriptTag.foucs();
refButton = '<div class="tableAction" id="senDiv">' +
                '<input id="importSce" name="importSce" type="button" value="Import" onclick="'+scriptTag+'"/>' +
                '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no need of `focus` method see this

```
serverURL = "http://google.com";  window.open(serverURL,'popUpWindow','height=500,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes');
```

check out [here](http://jsbin.com/gikut/1/) working example

Answer (score 0):

You've spelt focus wrong in your script. Check 'scriptTag.focus();'